# Refresh All Subform from Another Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have two main forms. One is the **Dashboard** and another is **Edit**.

After Editing, I have a button to reopen the Dashboard.
It can open the dashboard but I want it to refresh the subforms within that Dashboard.

Comment: Why would you need to refresh the subform? It should be 'fresh' when the Dashboard opens. Do you mean the Dashboard stayed open and you just want to return to it?

Comment: `Froms!Dashboard.Requery` will refresh the data in `Dashboard` form, if it is opened. If it is closed, just open it, and current data will be loaded int it.
Be sure data from `EDIT` form was updated to the data base. if not, use `Me.Rfresh` to save changes in the form to the data base. Find in [this link](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) to refer to a sub form

Comment: or you can you close the dashboard before opening again?

Answer (score 1):

This module will refresh the form you pass it, as well as all subforms. Requery will normally reset the selected item so before we requery we save the current record. If the record doesn't exist after requery it will gracefully go back to the top without error.

```
Public Sub RefreshForm(ByRef theForm As Form)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

    Dim thisRecord As Long
    thisRecord = theForm.CurrentRecord
    Echo False

    Dim childForm As Control
    For Each childForm In theForm.Controls
        If TypeOf childForm Is SubForm Then
            childForm.Requery
        End If
    Next

    With theForm
        .Requery
        .Recordset.Move thisRecord
    End With

ErrorHandling:
    Echo True
End Sub
```

To use it you simply drop this wherever you need a refresh:

```
RefreshForm Me
```

Comment: Aware that a simple`Requery`of the main form, requeries all subforms (if they are linked to main)? And by dimming`thisRecord`as an enum(`AcRecord`) it luckily gets implicit a`Long`! The usual code to recover form position after`Requery`uses the [Bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.bookmark) property.

Comment: Also you can't rely on`ControlType`as not all controls have that property (e.g. active x controls). Better use`If TypeOf childForm Is Subform Then`!

Comment: Thanks @ComputerVersteher but I wrote this because requery on my main form DID NOT requery the subform. My subform would show an entry that should have been filtered, only explicit requery on the subform makes the entry get filtered as expected. It is certainly linked to main.

Comment: Strange, as it works for me. Mainform is bound to a query? Please fix the error prone parts of your code (`Dim thisRecord As Long`and`If TypeOf childForm Is Subform`, remove or improve error handler, as it just exits on error without notify)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher The point of the error handler is to ensure that Echo gets turned back on. That's all it needs. If I removed that then you could be left in a state where the window won't update at all anymore.

Comment: Remove all`DoCmd.Echo`commands! No need for them here and if needed use [Appliation.Echo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.echo) as [DoCmd.Echo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.echo) is deprecated. Should error handler really ensure that errors are supressed? At least a msgbox should notify about the error.

Comment: Error handling is outside of the scope of this question but in this case, yes I do suppress errors here because it throws an error every time the Current record disappears. The GoToRecord fails when that record is gone and the first record remains selected. This is the desired behavior. This happens every time I refresh after a step is completed. I wouldn't throw an error at the user every time they complete a step. The same would be true when using your bookmark method.

Comment: I use echo false to suppress screen flashing during the update. Makes the interface look nice.

Comment: Intention to supress errors but run`Echo`before exit would be much clearer if you add an exit handler and leave the error handler empty except a jump to te exit handler, where`Echo`runs. If you want rhe procedure to exit on error on`GoToRecord`at least check`Err`object if that error occured and react if a different error occurs! But I would prefer checking for record stille exists before moving and not move if disappeared and avoi most `DoCmd`commands as there are more powerfull replacements for most (exceptions e.g`OpenForm`, `OutputTo`) . Replacement for`GoToRecord`is`Form.Recordset.Move`

Comment: Well, Exit Handler is a coding style. I believe each procedure should only have one exit point. Using `Exit` commands in handlers is spaghetti style. What is the benefit of using Recordset.Move over GoToRecord? Are they functionally the same? Is there a performance difference?

Comment: `DoCmd`is mostly used to run Microsoft Office Access actions from Visual Basic. `DoCmd.GoToRecord` can just reference the default instance of a form (by name), but`Form.RecordSet.Move`uses a reference to the form instance, not the name, that enables using of multiple form instances ( one form opened multiple times). Also that directly works on the`RecordSet`object, so you can use its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to close and reopen anything. Any opened form and the controls on it can be requeried from VBA code running anywhere. It gets a little convoluted with subforms.

To requery a subform control on the current form: `[SubformControlName].Requery`

To requery the form in a subform control on the current form: `[SubformControlName].Form.Requery`

To requery a control in a subform on the current form: `[SubformControlName].Form.Controls("ControlName").Requery`

To do any of the above operations on a different form in the application, prefix with `Forms![FormName].`

Example: `Forms![FormName].[SubformControlName].Form.Controls("ControlName").Requery`